# Why is Trigonometric Substitution Inverse Substitution?

Tags: calculus

I am mostly trying to figure out this writing from my this textbook I picked up.

[image]

All I see is the general form for the substitution rule. Also why does it matter that g (asinθ) is an inverse function?

Thank you and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 3):

They call it "inverse substitution" because typically (i.e. before learning trig substitution), you use substitution by introducing a new variable via the substitution $$\text{new variable} = f(\text{old variable}),$$ whereas with trig substitution you are introducing a new variable via $$\text{old variable} = g(\text{new variable}).$$

That's all they mean by "inverse substitution."  The reason $g$ needs to be invertible is because you are still essentially doing regular substitution via $$\text{new variable} = g^{-1}(\text{old variable}),$$ but in order for that to work you need $g^{-1}$ to be defined, i.e. $g$ needs to be invertible.

Comment: Thank you immensely.